# Firewall connections from every country in the world

Tags: firewall, logging

Ok, this is very interesting, and just [posted on Slashdot](http://ask.slashdot.org/story/10/01/23/2327204/Crazy-Firewall-Log-Activity-mdash-What-Does-It-Mean?art_pos=1) by someone (not me).

It appears that the guy receives packets in busts from all the countries in the world, and he does not understand what's going on. Any ideas?

Here is the [movie with the data](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sB2jEhDZyBk).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an advertisement for a company. I would think the data is bogus.

http://ask.slashdot.org/comments.pl?sid=1522194&cid=30874840

Comment: This is really sad...